# why does release return (oneway void) but autorelease return (id)?

Tags: objective-c

If I do this-

```
SomeObject* someObject = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
[[someObject release] release];
```

I presume my program wouldn't crash because the second over-release is acting on nothing.

Whereas

```
[[someObject autorelease] autorelease];
```

would crash because the object is released twice by being passed down the chain.

This is a matter of curiousity only, I guess I've never had a problem with it so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5495195/400056) for an explanation what `oneway` does.)*

Your first example doesn't even compile, as `void` != `nil`. But if you simply call `release` two times on an object that has a retain count of 1, it'll for sure crash.

As for why `release` returns `void` while `autorelease` returns `id`: The first says *I don't need this object any more, you may get rid of it.* Thus, if it would return something and you would operate on it you're likely to operate on a dead object. By contrast, `autorelease` more or less says *"Soon I won't be needing the object any more but let it stick around until I'm done with the current method."*

So as you see they are similar in that they say *I won't be needing this object any more*, but they differ in the time: `release` says *"you can get rid of the object **now**"*, while `autorelease` says *"you may get rid of the object **later**"*.

Comment: Good point about the compilation error- I presumed wrongly.  Question answered, thanks. :)  I suppose it does just come down to the fact you often return autoreleased objects but never a released one.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose this is mainly done for ease of use, as one could of course do without (and put every `autorelease` on its own line):

Whenever you `release` an object, you're done with it (or at least you should be). There is no need to return the object as it may well have been destroyed already and in any case the caller should not work with the object if it is not yet destroyed (i.e. someone else has a reference to it).

On the other hand `autorelease` is often used in conjunction with `init`/`alloc` and just marks the object for later destruction. Whenever using `autorelease` one can almost be sure that the object is being used afterwards. Whether you directly return it or work with it on your own (e.g. after `[[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease]`) it is very handy to have the object returned as it saves an explicit line of code for `autorelease`. It is also helpful to have the `autorelease` directly in the same line: On `return [someObject autorelease]` you can directly see, that this is an autoreleased object. If you use it with `init`/`alloc` you can directly see that this object does not need another `release`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you've answered your question yourself. Call to autorelease can be in the very beginning of object's life, so probably you'll need to save some code lines by the following statement:

```
[anotherObject callMethodWithArg: [myObject autorelease]];
```

Indeed, that's helpful. However, you call a release, in the very end of the code, that uses your object. By saying immediate release, you are saying you don't need this object here anymore. So there's no sense in reusing it's instance. Another option is, that a release call can actually deallocate the object immediately, so returning an invalid pointer will not be a good idea =)