# oneway modifier objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, distributed-objects

a `oneway` method is asynchronous (the result is not immediately expected)[[1]](http://chachatelier.fr/programmation/fichiers/cpp-objc-en.pdf). `oneway` is used with the distributed objects API. [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5495195/944634)

But i found below code in [SCPlugin](http://scplugin.tigris.org/)

```
+ (oneway void) executeShellCommandAsynchronously:(NSString*)command
{
    [[self taskForShellCommand:command] launch];

    return;
}

+ (void) refreshAllFinderItems
{
    //code
    if (cmd) {
        [ShellTask executeShellCommandAsynchronously:cmd];
    }
}
```

will `oneway` behave same in cocoa application(without distributed object)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just because it isn't a part of the distributed objects API, does not mean it won't function in the same way. The keyword is a compiler hint, and not much else.