# Is oneway supported in iOS4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, oneway

Looking at this article:
http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

I have implemented a singleton, my question is the oneway (not using ARC) is it supported in iOS 4.0?

Comment: "oneway" has nothing to do with ARC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is available, oneway is an objective c keyword, it does not relate to a given iOS SDK

Answer (score 1):

This is a design pattern which will remain unchanged as and when technology changes. So you can use it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , `oneway` keyword is a compiler hint.

Comment: It's actually a compiler hint, not a flag. -1 until fixed.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, check your answer on my question http://stackoverflow.com/a/9603670/944634 (Yes. Just because it isn't a part of the distributed objects API, does not mean it won't function in the same way. The keyword is a compiler flag, and not much else.)