# What is oneway Bool in objectC

Tags: objective-c, oneway

In my software, it has a function as below

`- (oneway BOOL)saveDocument:(INJDocument *)document`

I don't understand about `oneway Bool`. Can you explain to me What is the meaning of "oneway Bool"?, when should we use it?

Comment: You can read it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494981/use-case-of-oneway-void-in-objective-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use-case of \`oneway void\` in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494981/use-case-of-oneway-void-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oneway is used with the distributed objects API, which allows use of Objective-C objects between different threads or applications. It tells the system that it should not block the calling thread until the method returns. Without it, the caller will block, even though the method's return type is void.

Comment: You should reference the answer you copied and pasted this from. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5495195/268025